# shared declarative pipeline: overloading call operator while keeping access to pipeline steps

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a shared jenkins pipeline that is currently invoked via  it's `call()` operator.
The call method accepts a fixed set of parameters.
I want to change the `call()` signature to accept named parameters instead. This will make it easier to extend the parameters in the future.

Because I can not update all Jenkinsfiles at once that call the shared pipeline, I have to keep the signature compatible.
My idea was to override the `call()` method like:

```
// old call method
def call(String repo, String version) {
    call(repo: repo, version: version)
}

def call (Map params) {
    pipeline {
         agent { label 'master' }
         [...]
     }
}
```

If I invoke the pipeline with via `call("repo1", "master")`, it fails with: `No such DSL method 'agent'`.
It seems I lost access to the variable binding of the Jenkinsfile (?).

How do I ensure that the jenkins steps are still accessible when overloading `call()`?
Is there maybe a better solution to keep the shared pipelines compatible while changing the method signature?

Comment: Keep 1 method with declaration call(Object...params) and test inside if params is a map then... Else it's an array..

Comment: @daggett thanks, good Idea. It would great if there is a solution where I have at the end a `call()` method that I can pass named args (a Map only)

Answer (score 0):

According to this site: [Jenkins Templating Engine](https://jenkinsci.github.io/templating-engine-plugin/2.5/concepts/advanced/overloading-steps/) overloading of step should work. I checked it and it works on my env.

Seems like your issue with `No such DSL method 'agent'` connected to another issue, not to the overloading.